# How to add dynamic subdomain in my url without changing Route::group ("prefix"?

Tags: laravel, routes, wildcard-subdomain

http://localhost:8000/nameofUser/dashboard

nameofUser is dynamic, i dont want to change all of my URL.

Laravel Routing

Comment: This does not refer to subdomain. Right?

Comment: you can do `Route::group(['prefix' => '{nameofuser}'], function() { //your routes });`

Comment: when i call that routes i don't want to call with window.location.href="/{username}/dashboard" instead **window.location.href="/dashboard"** only. The /{username} is changing every login of user.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the route like :

```
Route::get('/{username}/dashboard', 'UserController@index')
```

In the UserController, u can load the respective user settings.

Comment: when i call that routes i don't want to call with window.location.href="/{username}/dashboard"  instead **window.location.href="/dashboard"** only. The /{username} is changing every login of user